# How Can I Create a Friendly Slug for a Dynamic Page?

Tags: functions, permalinks, page-template, rewrite-rules, slug

I built a dynamic page template that pulls biography information from a MySQL table.

The page works fine but the URL is ugly.

Officer-Biography/?ID=1

I have a set of canonical slugs that I want to use for each officer.

for example, Officer-Firstname-Lastname

I've tried both htacess and add_rewrite_rule and both give me 404.

example: `add_rewrite_rule('Officer-Erich-Abberger', 'Officer-Biography/?ID=1', 'top');`

What am I missing?

Comment: rewrite rules in WP aren't like Apache or Nginx, they're more like URL mapping rules, they take a regular expression and map values on to an `index.php?foo=bar` type string. It can only be `index.php?`, you can't rewrite a permalink on to another permalink, or a different file/path. Routing only, no redirects or remapping

Comment: Tom...thanks for the comment and clarification. I'm not able to find an effective way to do this in htaccess either. Any ideas?